# On Lego Mindstorms EV3, is there a way to change the input parameters of a My Block?

Tags: mindstorms, ev3, ev3-g

I am writing a program for which I did a My Block. I later realize that I need to add a new input parameter and I can't find a way of doing this without creating a new My Block. This seems it should be trivial but its driving me crazy not being able to find out how. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It's possible now, see https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/9278/9277

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to add a parameter to an existing MyBlock in both the NXT and EV3 series. You will have to create a new one with more input parameters.